# Need explanation for code in Caesar cipher

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

Hey so recently I got tasked with creating an app that reads a message and ecrypts it with the Caesar cipher in Java.

I didn't really have a problem until I came to the part where adding the numberic cipher would take you over letters a-z/A-Z into special symbols and I did not really know what to do.

Here is the code of my solution:

```
private String caesarCipher(String message) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder cipher = new StringBuilder();
    char ch;
    int key;

    System.out.print("Enter a key: ");
    key = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        ch = message.charAt(i);
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = (char)(ch + key);

            if(ch > 'z'){
                ch = (char)(ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
            }

            cipher.append(ch);
        }
        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = (char)(ch + key);

            if(ch > 'Z'){
                ch = (char)(ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
            }

            cipher.append(ch);
        }
        else {
            cipher.append(ch);
        }
    }

    return cipher.toString();
}
```

Could someone please explain to me the process and reasoning behind the following statement:

```
if(ch > 'z'){
    ch = (char)(ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
}
```

Comment: That is wrapping the values back to the start of the range.  You could do the same thing using `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never allow an encrypted character to exceed its supposed range, that is, a - z. The ascii of a and z are 97 and 122 respectively, and you would want the Caesar cipher encryption within this range of characters only.

This will check if the ascii code of `ch` is greater than the ascii of z

```
if(ch > 'z'){
```

If yes, it will calculate: (ascii of `ch`) - (ascii of `z`) + (ascii of `a`) - 1.

```
ch = (char)(ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
```

It is translated into `ch = (char)(ch - 122 + 97 - 1);`

Suppose you want to encrypt character `a` with a key `3`. The program will take 97 (ascii of `a`) + 3. You will get 100, which is the ascii of `d`. Yet, what if you want to encrypt `z` with a key `3`?

Same as before, it will take 122 (ascii of `z`) + 3 = 125. However, 125 is not found in the range 97 - 122 (a-z). Thus, you will get an unwanted character (in this case, 125 is the ascii of `}`).

Therefore, `(ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1)` will ensure that any character exceeding ascii 122, will be converted back into a character with ascii range of 97 and 122 inclusive only. In the example of 125, `ch = (char)(125 - 122 + 97 - 1)` => `ch = (char)(99)` => `ch = c`.